# Best way to get specific XML node value?

Tags: php, xml

I have this xml structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<log>
    <path>/dir/file</path>
    <name>log_</name>
</log>
```

this is my function:

```
function getNode($node)
{
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->load('config.xml');

    $value = $dom->getElementsByTagName($node);

    foreach($value as $val)
    {
        $ints = $val->getElementsByTagName($node);
        $intVal = $ints->item(0)->nodeValue;

        echo $intVal;
    }
}
```

how I can get the value of `path` node? I pass the node as parameter like `path`. But the code doesn't enter in the foreach. What I did wrong? I'm waiting the `/dir/file` result

Comment: Whats the value of `$node`?

Comment: @putvande as I said in the question the `node` value is `patch` and rapresent the node where I'm looking for the value

Comment: The DOM extension includes [DOMXpath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.evaluate.php) and allows you to use Xpath expressions to fetch nodes and scalar values from the document.

Answer (score 0):

I hope, this will help:

```
function getNode($node)
{
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->load('config.xml');

    $value = $dom->getElementsByTagName($node);

    if ($value->length > 0) {
        $intVal = $value->item(0)->nodeValue;
        echo $intVal;
    }
}
```

The explanation is very simple - there is [detailed manual](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) about using DOMDocument class, provided on [php.net](http://php.net/).

Comment: what I mean is: your answer is a code-only answer. The OP can copy and paste your code now, but probably won't learn without the explanation. This is true for future users as well. If the answer to OP's problem is easily found in the manual, then - instead of an answer - one might send the link to the manual as comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the node name 'path' to the function `getNode`. The function [getElementsByTagName](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) takes a string as a parameter and will return a [DOMNodeList](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php)  which you can loop using a `foreach`.

For example:

```
function getNode($node)
{
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->load('config.xml');

    $value = $dom->getElementsByTagName($node);

    foreach($value as $val)
    {
        $path = $val->nodeValue;
        echo $path;
    }
}

getNode('path');
```

Will result in:

> /dir/file

Answer (score -3):

You could use SimpleXml instead.
[simpleXml example - php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

Comment: I don't want use external resource, and also it's not an answer, is a comment.

Comment: My fault, sorry. Newbie here :/